# Show Two view controllers on screen using Storyboard, like SplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to Show Two view controllers on screen using Storyboard, like SplitViewController.
Apple SplitViewController not suitable for me, because left menu is to large and I need to change its width, but Apple doesn't does not allow it.

How to do this?

Thank you all for answers!

P.S. App for iPad.

Comment: "Use container view is also not suitable because I want to use navigation controller for right and left view separately" Why on earth not? Container view -> embed segue -> Navigation controller -> relationship -> root view controller, twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

!for your case give it a try using 2containerview in a viewcontroller
and embed segue from each of them . 
note you will have to control segues by your selves
check out this example for container view
[using container view](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

this example is using 1 container view . and you can easily customize this code , with 2 container views.
i want to try using container view like [image: my storyboard sample]
in this way you will have saparate navigation bar for left and right viewcontrollers.

i had made [simple demo](https://github.com/shujat89/two-container-view-in-a-controller) for this also :D

Comment: Containerview is also not suitable because I want to use navigation controller for right and left view separately.